# facing problem in dnn installation on my local machine

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have downloaded DNN from (https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/releases) Installation version and configured in my local machine by following all steps as they are given. I have given all permission (Read/Write/Modify) but at Installation time it gives Error see this errore http://prntscr.com/ogmkfi

I followed all steps before my last try then I do it well but this time I followed the same process but getting error

Answer (score 1):

The account that runs the application pool for the website needs Modify permissions on the whole directory structure where the web site is installed. Let's assume you have created a website in IIS called dnndevme, and created an application pool with the same name, then the account name is "IIS AppPool\dnndevme".

Normally I do it this way:

1. Create a folder in Windows Explorer, e.g. C:\Websites\dnndevme
2. Create a website in IIS Manager, e.g. dnndevme, and assign the created folder to the website. If you don't select another application pool, it will create one with the name of the website ("dnndevme"). Assign a host name, e.g. "www.dnndev.me"
3. In IIS Manager, select the web site, and double click on Authentication (under IIS). Then I select "Anonymous Authentication", click on the "Edit..." link on the right side and change the anonymous user identity to "Application Pool Identity".
4. Check: In IIS Manager, under Application Pools, right click the created (or selected) application pool and select "Advanced Settings...". Be sure that the value of "Identity" is "ApplicationPoolIdentity".
5. In Windows Explorer, right click the created folder and select the Security tab. click "Edit...", then click "Add..." and add the application pool identity, in the case of the example "IIS AppPool\dnndevme". Assign Modify permissions to that account.
6. Unblock and unzip the installation package into the folder.
7. In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), create a new database, eg. "dnndevme"
8. If SQL Server and IIS are installed on the same machine: In SSMS, create a new login. Select Login name = "IIS AppPool\dnndevme", Windows Authentication, Default database = "dnndevme". Under "User mappings" select the db_owner role for the database.
9. If SQL Server and IIS are on different machines you have to create an SQL Server Login (eg. "dnndevme") with a password, the other settings are as above.
10. Configure the connection string in the web.config file. If SQL Server is on the same machine, use

    ```
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=MY_MACHINE_NAME[\INSTANCE];Initial Catalog=dnndevme;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    ```

    Otherwise use

    ```
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=MY-SQL-SERVER-NAME[\INSTANCE];Initial Catalog=dnndevme;User ID=dnndevme;Password=mySEcrEtpaS$w0rd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    ```

Now start the installation wizard by navigating to the site in your browser (the defined host name from above).